# Email header for a profile picture or avatar?

Tags: python, email, email-headers, mailjet

I am playing around with the python mailjet api, and found that I can set the sender's name so instead of emails showing up from "Info" (info@example.com) I can have them show up from "Carlos". I would also like to add a profile picture like that of Southwest Airlines or Twitter.

[image]

Anyone have any idea how I might do that?

I know that if I don't post code then people get angry, so here's some code:

```
mailjet = Client(auth=(API_KEY, API_PASSWORD), version='v3.1')
data = {
    'Messages': [
        {
            "From": {
                "Email": "info@example.com",
                "Name": "Carlos"
            },
            "To": [
                {
                    "Email": trip.email
                }
            ],
            "Subject": "Subject of the message",
            "TextPart":"This is the body of the message",
            "Headers": {
                    "X-My-Header": "https://www.example.com/profile_pic.png"
            }
        }
    ]
}
mailjet.send.create(data=data)
```

Comment: Which mail program is that image from? Do you mean the icon in GMail/Inbox, which apparently [needs a verified Google+ presence](http://freshinbox.com/blog/how-to-get-your-logo-to-display-in-gmail-grid-view/).

Comment: It is... Looking at the link now. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

2022 update: The best method for this is [BIMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brand_Indicators_for_Message_Identification), **Brand Indicators for Message Identification**.

BIMI uses [DMARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC) to ensure authenticity and then allows specifying a brand logo registered as a trademark to be displayed in email clients (Google calls this a [Verified Mark Certificate](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10911028)).

I don't think there's a specification yet (see the [IETF BIMI draft](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-blank-ietf-bimi-02.txt) from 2021), so the best resource is the [BIMI Group](https://bimigroup.org/) itself.

---

There are two headers out there that may (but probably won't) work for you:

1. [X-Face](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Face)
2. [X-Image-URL](http://gigliwood.com/weblog/MacOSX/Putting_your_pictur.html)

Neither has great support.  X-Image-URL was supported in Apple Mail until v4.5.

It's not a header, but I think [Gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/) is probably the closest thing to what you're looking for.  With a Gravatar account, you can post an image to match your email's MD5 hash for various websites and email clients to pick up.  There are a few implementations of email client helpers/extensions/add-ons that apply sender email Gravatars to a message, including Thunderbird's [Contact Photos](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/contact-photos) add-on, but that doesn't even have broad adoption on Thunderbird, which itself doesn't have broad adoption.

I can't comment on how it's done with Google specifically, but many enterprise systems simply propagate your image from your account profile.

Note that this does introduce a new confidence indicator that can be abused by phishing attacks, though I haven't seen one yet.